# jQuery Filter and Reverse Filter

Tags: jquery

I'm looking for a shorter way of writing:

```
$('div')
.filter(function(value) {
   return runMyTestFunction(value);
})
.hide()
.end()
.filter(function(value) {
   return !runMyTestFunction(value);
})
.show();
```

Hopefully something along the lines of:

```
$('div')
.filter(function(value) {
   return runMyTestFunction(value);
})
.hide()
.end()
.remove(theLastWrappedSetPoppedOfftheJqueryStack)
.show();
```

I'd like to define 'runMyTestFunction' inline as a lambda since I think it will make the code clearer but as written I would have to duplicate it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could do:

```
$('div')
.filter(runMyTestFunction);
.hide()
.end()
.not(runMyTestFunction)
.show();
```

If you don't want to run the method twice:

```
$('div')
.hide() // hide all
.not(runMyTestFunction)
.show();
```

Or if you explicitly want to hide only certain elements:

```
var elements = $('div');
var toRemove = elements.filter(runMyTestFunction).hide();
elements.not(toRemove).show();
```

Comment: I like that third option best.  The first one still doesn't let me inline the function without duplication.  The second one could possibly produce some flicker by hiding elements then reshowing them - probably not but I'd rather avoid it.

Comment: Storing in a variable is a very clever solution. Cool!